# How to insert different value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

Suppose I have a name column with UNIQUE Constraint on it and it has  data ABC ,XYZ etc.And I want to insert more data.if the data are different then insert it.And take ABC  as same as Abc,abc,abC etc.

Comment: Yes!! You have to insert different name.

Comment: To clarify: are you asking how to make your unique constraint case-insensitive? Please edit your question to add more information - table structure, example current data, and examples of inserts you want to run - and what should happen to each (success, failure, errors you expect to see etc.).

Comment: @AlexPoole the question is about inserting a record if its unique value does not exist yet in the database.

Comment: @LajosArpad - the last sentence is about treating different cases as equivalent. Hence asking for clarification.

Comment: Yes last sentence is about treating different cases as equivalent. And ABC is just example .we have to make it for any string.if the word is present in the table and we want to insert same word with different case then it should throw an error that we cannot insert this data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if the word is present in the table and we want to insert same word with different case then it should throw an error that we cannot insert this data

You can use a unique function-based index to achieve this.

At the moment you have a unique constraint which is case-sensitive, e.g.:

```
create table your_table (name varchar2(30));
alter table your_table add constraint con_unique_name unique (name);

insert into your_table (name) values ('ABC');
insert into your_table (name) values ('XYZ');

commit;
```

That blocks an exact duplicate, but allows variations in case to be inserted:

```
insert into your_table (name) values ('ABC');

ORA-00001: unique constraint (STACK.CON_UNIQUE_NAME) violated

insert into your_table (name) values ('Abc');

1 row inserted.

insert into your_table (name) values ('abc');

1 row inserted.

rollback;
```

If you add a unique index that uses the upper-case version of the value (or lower-case; doesn't matter as long as it's consistent!) as well as, or instead of, your existing constraint then those would be blocked too:

```
create unique index idx_unique_name on your_table (upper(name));

insert into your_table (name) values ('ABC');

ORA-00001: unique constraint (STACK.CON_UNIQUE_NAME) violated

insert into your_table (name) values ('Abc');

ORA-00001: unique constraint (STACK.IDX_UNIQUE_NAME) violated

insert into your_table (name) values ('abc');

ORA-00001: unique constraint (STACK.IDX_UNIQUE_NAME) violated
```

Notice the reported constraint name is different for the first one - that is still hitting the original unique constraint, while the mixed-case ones are passing that constraint and then failing on the new index. If you dropped the original constraint then they would all fail on the new index.

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same

Answer (score 0):

You can do an insert-select, like

```
insert into yourtable(name)
select 'ABC'
from yourtable
group by ''
having count(*) > 0
where not exists (select 1 from yourtable yt where yt.name = yourtable.name);
```

(untested)

or you can wrap an if around the `insert` to see whether this name already exists.